# Глагол ПОДСКАЗАТЬ

Tags: стилистика

*Подсказать*, наиболее употребительное значение этого слова: «незаметно сказать кому-либо то, что тот должен сказать громко». Распространена подсказка в школе. Однако у многих сложилось ошибочное представление, будто подсказка -  явление, выходящее далеко за пределы школьных стен: Подскажите (правильно *скажите),* как пройти на улицу Строителей? Мне подсказали (правильно *посоветовали),* как обойти соперников. В первом из этих примеров наш глагол используется, как мы уже указали, в значении "сказать", а во втором - "посоветовать". Оснований для такого использования глагола "подсказать" нет никаких.

***Вопрос: для какого такого использования нет оснований у этого глагола? Читайте последнее предложение. Что-то не соображу.***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я думаю, речь идёт о культуре речи - или пуристы, или грамотная речь в школе.

У слова ПОДСКАЗАТЬ 2 значения:

1. Тихо и незаметно сказать, чтобы помочь кому-н. ответить на вопрос.
2. перен. Навести на мысль, внушить какие-н. действия, слова. *Случай подсказал мне правильное решение*.

В последнее время появилось значение:
3. Сказать, посоветовать (прост.). *Подскажите, как мне поступить. Не подскажете, как доехать до вокзала?* Его включила в словарь Шведова (совместный с Ожеговым), но как ПРОСТОРЕЧИЕ. Может, со временем появится помета "разговорное", а потом и в норму перейдёт, коль его так часто употребляют люди в этом значении, и грамотные в том числе, кажется, так более вежливо, ненавязчиво. Кстати, сама так говорю. Правда, употребить в письменной речи как литературное слово  мне бы в голову не пришло. Но язык-то живёт, изменяется, значение это уже почти всенародное.

Однако, когда требуется изысканно грамотная речь, нужно употреблять классические значения, не просторечные.

Comment: Людмила, в словарях нет ни пометы "разг" ни "прост". Как-то неясно написано!

Comment: А в каких словарях смотрели? У меня Ожегов старый, 1977 года,там 2 значения, а онлайн вот: http://poiskslov.com/word/%D0%

Comment: Словарь на Грамоте, словарь Ушакова. Там тоже два значения. Но без помет!

Comment: Ваша ссылка опять не работает!

Comment: Попробуйте эту http://tolkru.com/page/podskazaty.php

Comment: А у первых двух значений помет и нет, оба значения нейтральные.

Comment: Третье значение не ново, хотя и зафиксировано недавно; думаю, выражение "подскажите, как пройти..." и впредь останется просторечием: оно менее вежливо, чем простое "скажите пожалуйста", да и с "волшебными" словами не сочетается. Возможно, кто-то замечает в нём и оттенок заискивания (как бы "чуть-чуть сказать" просят), предпочитая естественные слова.

Comment: Полностью согласна, но бывает, что употребляю, почему - сама не знаю, наверное, стадный инстинкт "все говорят, значит, можно". А может, потому что в обыденной речи мы часто употребляем просторечия, даже от бранных слов не застрахованы, а уж такие считаются и вовсе невинными.

Comment: Возможно, в отдельных случаях такое слово оказывается точным. Например, человек своими усилиями нашёл город, улицу и нужный ему дом, а корпуса дома перед его глазами расположены так, что ему требуется небольшая "подсказка" жителей квартала - остальное он сам нашёл! Тут-то он интуитивно и выбирает это слово :)

Comment: Александр, если бы такое значение считалось бы просторечием, в словарях была бы помет. ''прост''. Но в словарях нет такой пометы. Да и само значение не ново. мне не раз доводилось слышать еще в советских фильмах. 

На самом деле, меня интересовало другое:**''Оснований для такого использования глагола подсказать нет никаких''**... Вот это предложение. Я читаю и не могу сообразить, что автора этого словаря имеют в виду.

Comment: Я думаю, что авторы имеют в виду "основания" для использования такого выражения в качестве универсальной просьбы (штампа) в стандартных ситуациях, вместо выражений "скажите пожалуйста", "вы не скажете, как пройти" и т.п. В общем случае спрашивающий не знает, насколько сложный ему требуется совет, поэтому до получения ответа принижать его до уровня "подсказки" у него нет оснований.

Comment: А по-моему подтекст может быть даже такой: мне не хотелось бы, чтобы вы, такой солидный и занятой человек, утруждали себя подробным ответом, я смею рассчитывать только на коротенькую  "подсказку".

Answer (score 3):

Попробуем считать значение глагола с его морфемного состава.

Приставка ПОД, как и все русские приставки, многозначна, но ее центральное значение условно можно обозначить как действие, направленное  снизу вверх в физическом плане, или как подчиненность снизу вверх в отвлеченном смысле. Поэтому подбираем подходящее значение.

1) Подсказать ответ на уроке - сказать/сделать что-то ТАЙНО: подсмотреть, подслушать, подбросить.

2) Подсказать, как пройти. Здесь значение незначительной интенсивности, ограниченных 
масштабов, дополнительности действия: подзабыть, подбодрить, подгладить, подработать.

Имеется в виду, что я примерно знаю маршрут, но мне нужно немного  дополнительной информации.

Значение приставок проверено по "Толковому словарю словообразовательных единиц" Ефремовой.

О СТИЛЕ

Нейтральный стиль: Скажите, пожалуйста, как пройти. (Лично я употребляю только эту форму).

Разговорный стиль: Подскажите, как пройти. Обычно: Вы не подскажете, как пройти.

Излишняя коннотация, которую несет в себе приставка ПОД, и определяет разговорность стиля. Мне кажется, что даже имеет уничижительный смысл: что-то вроде "вы уж извините, что я вас беспокою". Думаю, что разговорность выражения можно определить и без словаря.

Comment: Возможно, что в форме "подсказать" заключена   ещё просьба предоставить  МИНИМАЛЬНУЮ, а не полную информацию, чтобы излишне не утруждать отвечающего.

Comment: @Vera, Вы сможете объяснить мне это предложение ''Оснований для такого использования глагола подсказать нет никаких''.. ?

Comment: Да, Серж, я наконец прочитала ваш вопрос. Думаю, что "есть все основания для употребления этого глагола", только надо иметь представление о его смысле и стиле. По-моему, для глагола "подсказать" ясно просматривается ограниченность передаваемой информации в ЛЮБЫХ его значениях, а в значении "подсказать дорогу" присутствует излишняя вежливость, что определяет разговорность стиля.

Comment: Спасибо, Вера!