# Просьба ответить на вопросы в письме

Tags: грамотная-речь

В обращении с вопросами в какую-либо организацию или службу поддержки пользователей (абонентов мобильной связи, клиентов банка) или просто в деловом письме как следует попросить об ответе на эти вопросы?

"Скажите, пожалуйста" корректно ли?

"Не могли бы вы ответить?"

Answer (score 0):

Второй вариант нормален в процессе разговора. А первый хорош в начале как вступление.
А вообще, культурнее "подскажите".

Comment: "Подскажите" вместо "скажите" — это ужасно! Как "обозначает" вместо "означает", когда по смыслу подходит последнее.

Comment: @Артём Луговой Так что, лучше в письме употреблять "Скажите"?

Comment: "Подскажите" - это новая тенденция, а Артём живёт прошлым.

Comment: @Владимир *Скажите* - полное действие, возьмите, да и скажите. Соизвольте сказать. А *подскажите* - скажите чуть-чуть,  слегка, не напрягаясь, самую малость, не заставляя делать что-то большое да рассказывать. Вот в этом культура - не напрягать человека, чтобы он говорил в полную меру. Но если вопрос объёмный, то оно не подходит.

Comment: @Владимир: на мой взгляд, да.  Действительно, это новая тенденция, раньше так не говорили, мне она не нравится. Тут это обсуждалось: https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/50049/%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%94%d0%a1%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%97%d0%90%d0%a2%d0%ac. Совершенно не согласен с такой трактовкой Оледа (в комментарии на секунду раньше моего).