# Длина тире при оформлении диалога?

Tags: пунктуация, тире, оформление-текста

Скажите, пожалуйста, как оформлять тире в диалоге? Вот, к примеру:

> — Вне всяких сомнений, вы — сын своего отца, — сказал старик.

Как в этом случае нужно оформить второе тире? Я имею в виду, каким оно должно быть по длине? Коротким **–** или длинным **—**?

Нашла такие примеры:

1. век живи — век учись (тире);
2. 2010–2012 (короткое тире);
3. 5−2=3 (минус);
4. кое-что (дефис).

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой, а в чём принципиальная разница между "скажите" и "подскажите"? :) Погуглила и не поняла, почему нельзя было оставить так? Я ни в коем случае не считаю, что вы придираетесь (и я к вам не придираюсь тоже). Из-за пытливости ума и только :)

Comment: [Тут](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/50049/%d0%93%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%bb-%d0%9f%d0%9e%d0%94%d0%a1%d0%9a%d0%90%d0%97%d0%90%d0%a2%d0%ac) обсуждали. Мне бл**и**зко мнение Александра. Оно в комментариях. Сам привык говорить *(Простите), не подскажете..?* Теперь стыдно, что так говорил, отучаюсь. Бывает, даже начинаю говорить и сразу поправляюсь. А когда мне в трубку говорит робот: "Подскажите, вы решили свою проблему?", я злюсь и вешаю трубку. Это уже переходит границы. :))

Comment: Ага, почитала, поняла) Буду теперь тоже отучаться)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я считаю, что правильно ставить длинное тире для всех трёх в вашем случае. То есть с помощью Alt+0151. При обычной печати минус ставлю дефисный.

На [этом сайте](http://fantasts.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=6005) говорят вот что (один человек цитирует второго и отвечает ему, считаю его мысль правильной):

> > С дефисом всё более или менее понятно. Но как быть с тире? Какая длина правильная?
>
> Для диалогов и прямой речи в русской типографике правильная длина тире — «длинная».

В [Википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B5) звучит такая мысль:

> ***Длина*** русского тире правилами современной пунктуации и типографики также ***не оговаривается:*** неявно предполагается, что существует ***единственный знак тире,*** а длина его определяется шрифтом (для набора на узкую колонку может быть выбран шрифт с более короткими тире).

Comment: Я тоже склоняюсь к длинному тире во всех трёх случаях, но не возникает ли при этом путаница? Читая быстро, можно и не заметить, что после _вы_ не стоит запятая, и запутаться в том, когда начались слова автора. Вы-то, понятное дело, заметите :) Ну а как же мы, обыватели?)

Comment: Есть у меня и ещё один вопрос касаемо знаков препинания в диалоге, не знаю, оформлять ли его отдельно. Можно ли поставить многоточие в конце реплики перед словами автора? _— Вне всяких сомнений, вы — сын своего отца... — сказал старик._ Или задумчивость и паузу в диалоге можно выразить лишь в словах автора _задумался он, задумчиво произнёс он_? Искала, но не нашла. Как вы так ищете? Всё у вас находится)

Comment: По поводу путаницы: а может, после "вы" тире можно опустить? Если нет, тогда не вижу другого варианта. Я тоже могу сначала споткнуться о фразу, а потом понять, что к чему. Что касается многоточия, даже не знаю. Но выбрал бы второй вариант ("задумчиво произнёс он"). Хотя, с другой стороны, как отсутствие сомнений сочетается с задумчивостью или неуверенностью?))

Comment: Никак, конечно) Я применила к этому предложению, раз уж мы тут его рассматриваем, но я имела в виду в принципе многоточие перед тире в таком случае. Пусть в этом оно выражает не задумчивость, а , скажем, паузу в их разговоре.

Comment: _При обычной печати минус ставлю дефисный._ Что вы имели в виду?

Comment: Не думаю, что паузу правильно обозначить многоточием. Минус дефисный — имел в виду, что не делаю различия между минусом и дефисом, ставлю всегда дефис.

Comment: Извините, вмешаюсь в ваш диалог. Многоточие в прямой речи, как и в любом другом предложении, выражает разные эмоции и смыслы. В этом предложении - это может быть и задумчивость, и недосказанность мысли. Оформлено оно верно. См. [Знаки при прямой речи](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/164-znapr)

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, спасибо вам большое, что вмешались. А я искала вот [тут](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_193) и ещё в других местах, но всегда как _многоточие в диалоге_ и никак не находила. А что вы по поводу длины тире думаете?

Comment: Это больше вопрос типографского набора. В тексте, художеств. литературе и в т. ч. в Вашем предложении должны стоять одинаковые тире. А вот между цифрами рекомендуют ставить короткое тире без пробелов: _в 50–60-е годы_.  Но если нет технической возможности, то можно и длинное, но только не дефис, хотя на это особо никто внимания не обращает (разве что при проверке именно таких навыков). Вот ссылка, там очень все просто и сразу понятно:   https://writercenter.ru/blog/grammar/probely-tire-defisy-tochki-cifry-kavychki-abbreviatury-inicialy.html

Comment: Не соглашусь, что если цифровой интервал, то лучше длинное тире, чем дефис. Я бы поставил дефис, если нет короткого тире. Правда, именно в этом примере с годами было бы не очень хорошо повторение дефисов.

Comment: Так я же и написал, что тире, только не дефис.

Comment: Согласен, но применительно именно к этому примеру. А если только два числа, тогда в соответствии с моей первой фразой.

Comment: Я запутался уже! В интервале по правилам нужно тире.

Comment: Да, но не длинное.

Comment: Кстати, Артем, хотел внести правку в аш ответ с плюсом-минусом — добавить ссылку. Как раз ту, которая в этой переписке, последняя.

Comment: Артем, ржунемогу,  я об ентом же писал выше.

Comment: Спасибо, воспользуюсь ей тогда! Так я и говорю, что дефис лучше длинного тире в общем случае.

Comment: Да, его чаще всего и можно увидеть.

Answer (score 1):

В мою бытность работы в редакции журнала, корректор, Надежда Елезаровна, сказала мне так:

1. длинное тире (Alt+0151) — это обычное тире, так же начало диалога;
2. среднее тире (Alt+0150) — это интервал (например, 2020–2021 гг.), так же можно использовать как знак "минус" (симпатичнее смотрятся так: – + ×)
3. короткое тире (дефис) — это, собственно, дефис, ну и "минус" зачастую.

P.S. Только что посмотрел кучу старых книг — там все диалоги начинаются с длинного тире (0151).

Comment: В старых книгах нашлось 0151? Наверное и корректор в спортзале рассекает.